# How to ensure non-null value is set to an initially null property, while perform action upon value being set?

Tags: kotlin, observable

Assume there is a property which is null at first, I want to ensure that only non-nullable value set be set to this property. Besides, I want to perform some actions each time after this property is set.
I. I realized that if I am using Delegates.observable, I have to check internally that if the value is null before performing some action, and that I cannot avoid that null is set to the value (I can only observe when the value is setted already, not before)
ii. I cannot use lateinit, since then I cannot observe when the value is being set (setter syntax cannot work with lateinit)

What I can think of is to have a custom setter function for that value, and declare the parameter as non-nullable.
Like below:

```
class Test {
    private var initialNull: String? = null

    private fun setInitial(nonNullValue: String) {
        initialNull = nonNullValue
        onInitialSet()
    }
}
```

Do you think it is a good idea?

I though of another idea that, I could create a custom ReadWriteProperty, e.g. NonNullableSetterObservable (initialValue), where null can be passed to initialValue at first, yet only non-null value can be set later on. Is it a good idea?

Comment: Wow thanks, someone is very cautious of syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oddly enough, it sounds like you need some of the functionality of all three of the standard library delegates - [`observable`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.properties/-delegates/observable.html), [`vetoable`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.properties/-delegates/vetoable.html) and [`notNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.properties/-delegates/not-null.html) - in the same property.

Writing your own delegate for this as you've mentioned is indeed a great idea, here's one implementation based on `ObservableProperty` (if I understood your requirements correctly):

```
public inline fun <T: Any> initialNull(crossinline onChange: (oldValue: T?, newValue: T) -> Unit): ObservableProperty<T?> {
    return object: ObservableProperty<T?>(null) {
        override fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T?) {
            value ?: return
            super.setValue(thisRef, property, value)
        }

        override fun afterChange(property: KProperty<*>, oldValue: T?, newValue: T?) {
            onChange(oldValue, newValue!!) // ugly but safe !!
        }
    }
}
```

Usage looks like:

```
var initialNull by initialNull<String> { oldValue, newValue ->
    println("Changed from $oldValue to $newValue")
}

initialNull = "Foo" // Changed from null to Foo
initialNull = null
initialNull = "Bar" // Changed from Foo to Bar
```

Comment: Thx, that's what I want. Maybe I am greedy 

Comment: findBugs would warn this approach as well, it is not a bug free one.